# how to set alternateHostName to all websites on iis 10?

Tags: security, iis-10

this refers to CVE: [CVE-2000-0649](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2000-0649)

```
appcmd.exe set config "SiteName" -section:system.webServer/serverRuntime /enabled:"True" /commit:apphost

appcmd.exe set config "SiteName" -section:system.webServer/serverRuntime /alternateHostName:"development-server-iis.local" /commit:apphost
```

the solution was found here: [internal-ip-address-leak-iis10](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1982074-internal-ip-address-leak-iis10)

my Question - Since I have many websites hosted on a single server, not all of them "named" - how to I make this setting work for all sites on that server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use PowerShell:

```
 Get-ChildItem iis:\sites | Foreach-Object {

 Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -location "$($_.Name)" -filter "system.webServer/serverRuntime" -name "enabled" -value "True"
 Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -location "$($_.Name)" -filter "system.webServer/serverRuntime" -name "alternateHostName" -value "development-server-iis.local"

 }
```

All web sites in IIS are named, this code just loops through them and runs the sets the two properties for all of them.